# How to disable email validation in rails device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, device

I need you help

Try: `model/user.rb`
[link to source](http://pastebin.com/zjgZdctw)

but it does not work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I do users CRUD in my site. I want to allow users to be created without email

Comment: why you try to disable email validation?

Comment: View my update answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply comment out the line specifying validators for the email attribute, or remove it altogether:

```
# app/models/user.rb
# validates :email, :presence => false, :email => false
```

You'll also need to make a slight modification to your `users` table. By default, Devise does not allow the `email` field to be null. Create and run change a migration that allows `email` to be `null`.

```
# in console
rails g migration AddChangeColumnNullToUserEmail

# migration file
class AddChangeColumnNullToUserEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true 
    end

    def self.down
        change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => false 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the [link](https://github.com/welcu/devise/blob/e8b01c1677047328d947f297123d34183588ef81/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) to the validate.rb file of devise. You can see a method email_required? in the model. So I guess

```
def email_required?
    false
end
```

in your User model should remove the necessity while registering.

Answer (score 3):

From this question, I guess, your email field is not required field.
IF this,
Try just remove the code: `:validatable` from your user.rb mudel.

Comment: This code does not work, validation still works