# Using mobile number instead of using the default email in device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, authentication, devise

I am new to ruby am trying to teach myself ruby on rails by watching some tutorial.

Last week I came to know about device I tried it but is there any way to change the default email attribute to something like mobile numbers.

I hope it is possible I came a cross of lots of things but there was nothing really helpful.

I hope for help. Thanks in advance.

**new.html.erb-registration**

```
<div class="row vertical-offset-100">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

    <fieldset>
      <h1 class="text-center login-title">Get In It's Free!</h1>  
      <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: "What's Your Awesome Name?" %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: 'And Your Beutiful Last Name' %>
      <%= f.input :phone_number, placeholder: 'number' %> 
      <%= f.input :password, placeholder: 'Make A Strengthfull Password' %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Make A Strengthfull Password' %>
          <div><%= f.button :submit, "Dale! (Go Ahead)", class: "btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch("/assets/shifting.jpg", {speed: 500});
    </script>
```

**new.html.erb-sessions**

```
<div class="row vertical-offset-100">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

    <fieldset>
      <h1 class="text-center login-title">Get In With Your</h1>  
    <%= f.input :phone_number, placeholder: 'Phone Number' %>
    <%= f.input :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>


    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %></div>
    <% end -%>

    <div><%= f.button :submit, "Just Sign In!", class: "btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" %></div>
      <% end %>
      <p> 
</p>
              <div class="text-center">
          <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
<p> 
</p>
<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up Now", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch("/assets/bg.jpg", {speed: 500});
    </script>
```

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = 'e8406bef31a2c5607f3ab4eb0d165f5745a03fca20a9fa7baedd70bc3ffdec638376dda3ac58efb35dbcbaa955b897dcd5519d7458527955af6e9e8d6c9fafb6'

  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.authentication_keys = [:phone_number]
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :shipments
         has_many :comments

         def full_name
          first_name + " " + last_name
        end
         def email_required?
          false
        end
     end
```

**registration_controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you read [`Devise Wiki`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) Specially [`How To: Allow users to sign in with something other than their email address`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it. You need to add the following code in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = "Whatever is your secret key"
  config.authentication_keys = [ :phone_number ]
end
```

In your `login` views you have to add the following `text_field` instead of the email field like this -

```
<%= f.text_field :phone_number, :class => 'Name of your class', :placeholder => "Phone Number" %>
```

After this step follow this [How to disable email validation in rails device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021367/how-to-disable-email-validation-in-rails-device) .

Add this to your **registration_controller** instead of what you have written:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
    u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

That's it

Comment: it's giving the following error
undefined method `phone_number' for #<User:0x4d48748>

Comment: Is there a `phone_number` column in your `Users` model? If not you will have to create one.

Comment: sir sorry for asking a stupid question like this but how to create a phone_number column. I really don't know much about these things but i am trying to learn

Comment: You can do like this - `rails g migration AddPhoneNumberToUsers phone_number:string`. You will have to run this command in your terminal.

Comment: @Denialsmith  Were you able to run it?

Comment: no sir it didn't work actually everything is working properly but when i give a phone number in the phone number field it says: ` 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Email can't be blank `

@nik

Comment: I think you should look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021367/how-to-disable-email-validation-in-rails-device) . It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks once again sir @nik you really helped a-lot

Comment: No issues . It was fun

Comment: hey sir sorry to disturb you again but actually i had editted the views of my devise new registration and session files and it's works but after that again my app is showing error when am trying to log in or sign up with my phone number attribute...i had tried all deleted all the users and post from the data base but it does't work...actually it's not showing any error but not getting me in of my app saying: **Invalid phone_number or password.** @nik

Comment: @Denialsmith It is difficult to say what the problem is, please update your whole code related to devise- models, views & controller or whatever is there. Better is if you take a look at this link [Devise login using phone number](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Comment: hey sir sorry am bothering you but can you please check this out once for me... i had updated my question with all the views models and controller files @nik

Comment: Dude did you run the migration told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021367/how-to-disable-email-validation-in-rails-device)

Comment: Yup i had did that too @nik

Comment: @nik.. It is very difficult to say like that. Please check your log and your Database Users table to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Logs show this which i cannot understand: **Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, password_confirmation**

Comment: This Unpermitted parameters is showing when you submit the login form or registration form?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: @Denialsmith I have updated the answer with registration_controller change see that.

Comment: yes Unpermitted parmeters are showing after submitting the form. Am using rails 4.2.3. your updated answer did not did anything @nik

Comment: @Denialsmith - Check your logs, are you still getting the unpermited parameters error?